# Logic for Computer Science - how to inductively define msort, split and merge of lists

Tags: logic, induction, computer-science

In "Modelling Computing Systems: Mathematics for Computer Science", I came across a logic exercise to inductively define a merge sort function 'mergeSort', with a hint to first define auxillary functions 'split' and 'merge'. The style of the logic so far looks like this for inductively defined sets Odd and Even, and some other functions that manipulate lists (isort, insert, length, append):

```
1 ∈ Odd;
if n ∈ Odd then (n+2) ∈ Odd;
0 ∈ Even;
if n ∈ Even then (n+2) ∈ Even;

isort([]) = []; 
isort(a:L) = (insert a)(isort(L));

(insert a)[] = [a]; 
(insert a)(b:L) = if a < b then a:(b:L) else b:((insert a)L);

length([]) = 0; 
length(n:L) = 1 + length(L);

L1 ++ [] = L1; 
(a:L1) ++ L2 = a:(L1 ++ L2);
```

I have tried, but I can't figure out how to define the first auxillary function 'split', which should split a list in roughly the same size. So far, I've defined the base cases for empty list and list with single element, but I don't know how to define the inductive case. I am not sure about the logic, the notation and also not about how I could make sure that the function doesn't use the same tail of the list L?

```
split([]) = ([],[]);
split(a:[]) = ([a],[]);
split(a : b : L) = if length(a : b : L) ∈ Even 
                     (a : (split(L)), b : (split(L)));
                   else 
                     (a : (split(L)), b : (split(b : L)));
```

How can I inductively call the split function again, without repeating the same split?

I have defined the merge function like this, and am pretty sure that should work:

```
merge(L1,[]) = L1;
merge([],L2) = L2;
merge(a:L1, b:L2) = if a < b 
                      (a:(merge(L1, b:L2))); 
                    else 
                      (b:(merge(a:L1, L2)));
```

As for the final function mergeSort, I've gotten this far:

```
mergeSort([]) = [];
mergeSort(a:[]) = [a];
mergeSort(L) = merge("firstResultOf"(split(L)), "secondResultOf"(split(L)));
```

I don't know how to make it clear in the function that merge should use the first and second output lists of split. And I am unsure how to call mergeSort inductively..

How would you do it, using this type of notation?

Comment: You shouldn't have to consider odd and even length lists. Just use integer division and take the first sublist to go from the first element up to the length / 2 element and the second sublist to be the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exercise (8.10) is a bit of a bump in difficulty. Maybe some intermediate steps will help in building up to a solution, plus giving some extra practice in these recursive definitions.

For the `split` function, there are several ways to conceive of breaking down a list into two equal(ish) parts. Let's not worry at all about computational efficiency, but just think about ways to define it. In context, we don't need this split to be the front and back halves of the given list - it could be any of the elements, in any order, so long as the sizes are about right.

If we do want to do front and back halves, we need to know how long the list is. Luckily you have a function `length` to do that. Can you define the following functions recursively?

1. `take n L`  - which gives the first `n` elements of `L` (if `n` is zero, that's an empty list; if it's bigger than `length L` then we'll get the whole of `L`)
2. `drop n L` - which returns the elements of `L`, *after* the first `n` (if `n` is zero, that's just `L`)

Having done that, can you put `take`, `drop` and `length` together to make `split`? Looking at your tentative definition, you already have the idea of adjusting the logic based on whether the length is odd or even, which is the right idea. However, the existing definition is not quite right on the recursion, because if `split` is producing a *pair* of lists, then `a:(split L)` doesn't work. The `take`/`drop` idea sidesteps that by putting the recursion into those functions. I do like what you did with `merge` where the structure is doing the right thing, so hopefully with another stab at these you can build more familiarity with this kind of definition.

As an *alternative* way to make `split`, can you recursively define -

1. `evens L` - returning those elements of `L` with even indices, e.g. `evens [3, 6, 1, 2]` yields `[3, 1]`
2. `odds L` - the other elements, so `[6, 2]` if applied to the list above.

Perhaps you can even see a clever way to do some mutual recursion between these. Then, defining `split` should not be very much extra work.

You also ask about something like

```
  merge("firstResultOf"(split(L)), "secondResultOf"(split(L)))
```

I am here to tell you that you can define a function `firstResultOf` that takes a pair `(x, y)` and returns `x`, and likewise `secondResultOf`. It may be bothering you that we're computing `split(L)` twice, but it doesn't bother me because we're not worrying about the cost of anything - just trying to come up with a definition that actually works. (And as you note, there should be some inner calls to `mergeSort` as well, to sort the sub-lists.)